# Display multiple trend lines in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, trendline

I have a table as follows,

```
    id    | membership |   month    |   year     |   numberofXPurchased
----------+------------+------------+------------+-------------------
     1    |    05      |    02      |   2014     |          5
     1    |    06      |    03      |   2014     |          7     
     1    |    07      |    04      |   2014     |          3
     2    |    01      |    11      |   2014     |          2
     2    |    02      |    12      |   2014     |          1
     2    |    03      |    01      |   2015     |          4
```

I created a line graph using ggplot to identify the correlation between the membership period and the number of time X was purchased

```
ggplot(data = df, aes (x = memberMonths, y=numberofXPurchased, group=id, color = id)) +
geom_line() +
geom_point() + 
theme(legend.position = "none") +
labs(y="Membership in Months", x = "X purchased")
```

This produces a line graph as expected, but as I have over 100000 rows of data, the plot is not interpretable. So I'm trying to display only trend lines instead of the lines representing each id, where 1 trend line to represent the entire plot, and a set of trend lines for each 'year' (Maybe in another plot).

Adding

```
stat_smooth( method="lm") or
geom_smooth(method = "lm")
```

Only adds the trend line to the existing plot, but I want the trendline instead of the data from df

Is there an efficient way to do this, Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you please add more data (representative dataset) using `dput` function?

Answer (score 2):

You can use geom_smooth(), with the 'lm' option gives a linear model

```
geom_smooth(method = "lm")
```

Show your code would look like..

```
    ggplot(data = df, aes (x = memberMonths, y=numberofXPurchased,group=id, color = id)) +
    geom_smooth(method = "lm") +
    geom_point() + 
    theme(legend.position = "none") +
    labs(y="Membership in Months", x = "X purchased")
```

As it appears `geom_smooth()` needs `geom_point()` to give the correct trendline I would use `alpha=0` within the `geom_point()` call.

```
    ggplot(data = df, aes (x = memberMonths, y=numberofXPurchased,group=id, color = id)) +
    geom_smooth(method = "lm") +
    geom_point(alpha=0) + 
    theme(legend.position = "none") +
    labs(y="Membership in Months", x = "X purchased")
```

Comment: This will add a new line to the existing graph, I do not want to display the existing points in the graph, but only the trend lines (As the existing lines are not interpretable due to the high volume)

Comment: Edited the question to make my requirement more clear

Comment: It is the `geom_point()` that adds the dots to for each data point. So your code was fine just dont include the geom_point() function. ggplot builds up so if you feel like there is too much remove parts :)

Comment: Correct me if i'm wrong, but my understanding is geom_smooth / stat_smooth function smoothes the points to generate the trend line, so without the geom_line and geom_point, it will not provide the correct trend line. I tested this and got an incorrect trend line,

Comment: I am unsure how consistent that is, either way you can then just set the opacity to 0 of the `geom_point()`  function, which is 'geom_point(alpha=0)` - I have updated my original answer